# ThreadPoolTaskExecutor Getting Overwritten in Scheduled Class

Tags: spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, threadpoolexecutor

I have the following ThreadPoolTaskExecutor thats gets created with the expected core/max pool size configurations.

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class ThreadPoolConfig {

    @Value("${corePoolSize}")
    private Integer corePoolSize;

    @Value("${queueCapacity}")
    private Integer queueCapacity;

    @Value("${maxPoolSize}")
    private Integer maxPoolSize;

    @Bean(name="myThreadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor myThreadPoolTaskExecutor() {       
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();       
        executor.setBeanName("myThreadPoolTaskExecutor");
        executor.setCorePoolSize(corePoolSize);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(queueCapacity);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("my_thread_");
        executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        executor.initialize();
        log.debug("threadPoolTaskExecutor CorePoolSize is  : " + executor.getCorePoolSize());
        log.debug("threadPoolTaskExecutor MaxPoolSize is  : " + executor.getMaxPoolSize());
        return executor;
    }
}
```

When my @scheduled method runs the max pool size is set to the DEFAULT value of `2147483647` and I don't understand why it's not using the configured `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` above:

```
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulingConfig {

}


@Component
public class Scheduler {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myThreadPoolTaskExecutor")
    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor;


    @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${fixedRate}")
    public void invokeScheduledThread() {

        while (threadPoolTaskExecutor.getActiveCount() <= threadPoolTaskExecutor.getMaxPoolSize()) {
            log.debug("Active Thread Pool count is : " + threadPoolTaskExecutor.getActiveCount() + ", Max Thread Pool count is : " + threadPoolTaskExecutor.getMaxPoolSize() + " on the scheduled Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

            //call a service to retrieve some items to process 
            threadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(Some Object that implements runnable);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

Active Thread Pool count is : 0, Max Thread Pool count is : `2147483647` on the scheduled Thread : `task-scheduler-1`

I put a break point into the `initialise()` method of `org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ExecutorConfigurationSupport`
and it looks like the method is getting invoked 3 times, twice with a ThreadName Prefix of "my_thread_"
which is expected and finally once for a Bean called "`taskScheduler`" with a ThreadName Prefix of "`task-scheduler-`".

Does anyone know why I can't use my own `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` within the Scheduler class?

I wanted to use a default @Scheduler to run on a single thread every x number of seconds and create X number of Threads using my own ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.

Comment: Try removing the SchedulingConfig class with the @EnableScheduling annotation.

Comment: @spekdrum i tried removing the `SchedulingConfig` class but the max thread pool count is still set to `2147483647`

Comment: I created and asnwer, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Use ThreadPoolTaskScheduler instead of ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.
For example:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSchedulerConfig {

    private static final int THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 5;

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler getScheduler() {

        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();

        //we want every Job in a separate Thread.
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(THREAD_POOL_SIZE);

        return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
    }

}
```

Comment: when the `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` @Bean is initialised with 10 and i @autowire it into the SchedulerClass, the log displays the following: `Active Thread Pool count is : 1, Max Thread Pool count is : 1 on the scheduled Thread : my_thread_1` so does calling getPoolSize() on the `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` return the Max Pool Size?

Comment: Documentation says "current pool size" https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.html#getPoolSize-- but it should return the max size I think. To get the active threads there's another method

Comment: Excellent thank you for your help.  One last thing do i need `@EnableScheduling` class?

Comment: U r welcome. I don't think so, I did several scheduled tasks in Spring Boot without @EnableScheduling. Spring Boots magic ;)

Comment: I'm looking at the implementation of the `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` and wondering how i can use this to execute all Threads within the Thread pool within one pass of the @Scheduler? With the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor there is a maxPoolSize so in my code i could say `while (threadPoolTaskExecutor.getActiveCount() <= threadPoolTaskExecutor.getMaxPoolSize()) {`

Comment: Maybe you should treat separately the scheduled task and the threads you want to run. Take a look here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method.

Comment: Thanks spekdrum, i think this is exactly what i'm looking for . After I `@EnableAsync` in my `ThreadPoolConfig` is it just a case of annotating a new public method with @Async that calls `threadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(....) and then call the new public method from the Scheduler class?`

Comment: The method annotated with @Async will run in a separate thread when invoked. You don't need to do ```threadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(....)```. You can call it from you Scheduler class. From there you should also be able to check the threads available from the pool injecting the configured ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.

Comment: `@Component
public class Scheduler {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myThreadPoolTaskExecutor")
    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor;

 @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${fixedRate}")
 public void invokeScheduledThread() {  
  checkForItemsToProcess(); 
 }
 
 
 @Async("wfThreadPoolTaskExecutor")
 public void checkForItemsToProcess() {
  while (threadPoolTaskExecutor.getActiveCount() <= threadPoolTaskExecutor.getMaxPoolSize()) {
   
   //call a service to retrieve some items to process on a new thread each time its called
  }
 
 }
}`

Comment: can you look at the above and see if i have the right idea?

Comment: I have my configuration `@Bean("asyncExecutor")` configured correctly now but when i call the method annotated with `@Async("asyncExecutor")` directly from the `@Scheduler` class it always uses the same Thread Name: `Executing method with the following asyncExecutor : task-scheduler-1`